# Some Woocommerce scheduled actions are not running

Tags: wordpress, docker, woocommerce

I noticed that in `Woocommerce -> Status -> Scheduled Actions` a bunch of tasks were created related to the new orders and left as Pending. The task is called `wc-admin_import_orders` and has an argument like `0 => xxx` (the `xxx` is the order id).

As a consequence of this issue, the data about the costumers from the `Woocommerce -> Customers` does not get updated.

I can run them manually, but I would like it to happen automatically, as it is supposed to. What could be the issue?

I am running Wordpress in a Docker container on my local machine.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I did not. I also stopped using Woocommerce due to other priorities. Nevertheless, I am not sure I would choose Woocommerce again if we restart the project.